# Trouble with ifelse statement with three options

Tags: r

I'm having trouble with transforming a variable.

I have a variable called Originating_body (currently a factor but I have also tried as.character to no avail) which consists of 13 types which I would like to reduce to 3 types called origin.simple.

| Originating_body | origin.simple |
| --- | --- |
| "Court (Second Section)" | Chamber |
| "Court (Second Section)" | Chamber |
| "Court (Second Section)" | Chamber |
| "Court (Fourth Section)" | Chamber |
| "Court (Third Section)" | Chamber |
| "Court (First Section Committee)" | Committee |
| "Court (Third Section Committee)" | Committee |
| "Court (Fifth Section Committee)" | Committee |
| "Court (Chamber)" | Chamber |
| "Court (Plenary)" | Grand Chamber |
| "Court (Grand Chamber)" | Grand Chamber |

the full list of variable transformations are:

> New Category: "Grand Chamber" made up of "Court (Grand Chamber)"
> "Court (Plenary)")
>
> New Category "Chamber", made up of "Court(Chamber)" "Court(Fifth
> Section)" "Court(First Section)" "Court(Fourth Section)" "Court(Second
> Section)" "Court(Third Section)"
>
> New Category "Committee" Made up of: "Court Fifth Section Committee"
> "Court(First Section Committee)" "Court(Fourth Section Committee"
> "Court(Second Section Committee" "Court(Third Section Committee"

there are no missing values

Example-data:

```
df<-data.frame(Originating_body) 
Originating_body <- c("Court (Fourth Section)", "Court (Fourth Section)", "Court (Fourth Section)", 
                    "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Grand Chamber)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Fourth Section Committee)", "Court (Chamber)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Grand Chamber)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (Plenary)", "Court (First Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (Fifth Section)", "Court (Fifth Section)", 
                    "Court (Fifth Section)", "Court (Grand Chamber)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section Committee)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Fourth Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Fourth Section)", "Court (Fourth Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section Committee)", "Court (First Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Fifth Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Fifth Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Fifth Section)", 
                    "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section Committee)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Fifth Section)", "Court (Fifth Section Committee)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section Committee)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
                    "Court (First Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Fourth Section Committee)", 
                    "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section Committee)", "Court (Second Section)", 
                    "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)")
```

I have tried to do it with an ifelse statement,

```
df$origin.simple <- ifelse(df$Originating_body =="Court (Grand Chamber)"|
                         df$Originating_body == "Court (Plenary)", "Grand Chamber", 
                ifelse(df$Originating_body =="Court(Fifth Section)"|
                          df$Originating_body == "Court(Fourth Section)"|
                          df$Originating_body == "Court(Third Section)"|
                          df$Originating_body == "Court(Second Section)"|
                          df$Originating_body == "Court(First Section)"|
                          df$Originating_body == "Court(Chamber)", "Chamber", "Committee"))
```

but something goes wrong, the "Grand Chamber" seems to be correct, but I end up with "Committee" where I wanted "Chamber" so R ignores the second part of the ifelse statement and transforms "Court(Fifth Section)","Court(Fourth Section)","Court(Third Section)","Court(Second Section)","Court(First Section)" and "Court(Chamber)" into "Committee" rather than "Court".

I'm sure there is an obvious mistake that I've made but I cannot seem to find it. I've also tried with grepl(ifelse()) rather than ifelse() but without any success. Help would be much appreciated, thank-you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you please use `dput()` to get your example data frame in a copy-pastable format and add it to your question as a code block?

Comment: I've added an answer with a couple of approaches, but the main thing you're probably falling foul of is typos - your data has spaces such as "Court (Third Section)" but your code doesn't ("Court(Third Section)") and therefore no match is found.

Comment: Thank-you very much. I've tried to edit the question, but I'll definitely first have a look at any typos. Thanks for helping out. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing your data frame to an object `df`:

```
df <- read.table("clipboard", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
```

Preparing categories, note you had typos here that were probably the main source of the trouble:

```
GrandChamber <- c("Court (Grand Chamber)", 
                  "Court (Plenary)")

Chamber <- c("Court (Chamber)", 
             "Court (Fifth Section)", 
             "Court (First Section)", 
             "Court (Fourth Section)", 
             "Court (Second Section)", 
             "Court (Third Section)")

Committee <- c("Court (Fifth Section Committee)",# fixed missing brace
               "Court (First Section Committee)",
               "Court (Fourth Section Committee)", # fixed missing brace
               "Court (Second Section Committee)", # fixed missing brace
               "Court (Third Section Committee)") # fixed missing brace
```

Nested `ifelse()` version:

```
df$new <- ifelse(df$Originating_body %in% GrandChamber, "Grand Chamber",
                 ifelse(df$Originating_body %in% Chamber, "Chamber",
                 ifelse(df$Originating_body %in% Committee,"Committee", "ERROR")))
```

My preferred approach using `dplyr` and `case_when()`:

```
df$new <- dplyr::case_when(df$Originating_body %in% GrandChamber ~ "Grand Chamber",
                         df$Originating_body %in% Chamber ~ "Chamber",
                         df$Originating_body %in% Committee ~ "Committee"
                 )
```

Using a named vector and subsetting (with thanks to @Onyambu):

```
lookups <- c("Court (Grand Chamber)" = 'Grand Chamber', 
             "Court (Plenary)" = 'Grand Chamber',
             "Court (Chamber)" = 'Chamber',
             "Court (Fifth Section)"= 'Chamber', 
             "Court (First Section)"= 'Chamber', 
             "Court (Fourth Section)"= 'Chamber', 
             "Court (Second Section)"= 'Chamber', 
             "Court (Third Section)"= 'Chamber',
             "Court (Fifth Section Committee)" = 'Committee',
             "Court (First Section Committee)" = 'Committee',
             "Court (Fourth Section Committee)" = 'Committee',
             "Court (Second Section Committee)" = 'Committee',
             "Court (Third Section Committee)" = 'Committee')

df$new <- lookups[df$Originating_body]
```

each approach gives

```
                  Originating_body origin.simple           new
1           Court (Second Section)       Chamber       Chamber
2           Court (Second Section)       Chamber       Chamber
3           Court (Second Section)       Chamber       Chamber
4           Court (Fourth Section)       Chamber       Chamber
5            Court (Third Section)       Chamber       Chamber
6  Court (First Section Committee)     Committee     Committee
7  Court (Third Section Committee)     Committee     Committee
8  Court (Fifth Section Committee)     Committee     Committee
9                  Court (Chamber)       Chamber       Chamber
10                 Court (Plenary) Grand Chamber Grand Chamber
11           Court (Grand Chamber) Grand Chamber Grand Chamber
```

Comment: use a named vector, ie `c("Court (Grand Chamber)"='Grand', "Court (Plenary)"='Grand', ...)[originating_vector]`

Comment: @Onyambu yes, that's definitely a valid approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy using a dictionary which you obviously already made.

```
> transform(dat, 
+           ob_new=dict$origin.simple[match(dat$Originating_body, 
+                                           dict$Originating_body)])
                  Originating_body        ob_new
1            Court (First Section)       Chamber
2            Court (First Section)       Chamber
3            Court (Third Section)       Chamber
4            Court (Fifth Section)       Chamber
5           Court (Second Section)       Chamber
6  Court (First Section Committee)     Committee
7            Court (First Section)       Chamber
8            Court (Third Section)       Chamber
9            Court (Third Section)       Chamber
10           Court (First Section)       Chamber
11          Court (Second Section)       Chamber
12           Court (Grand Chamber) Grand Chamber
13           Court (Third Section)       Chamber
14           Court (Third Section)       Chamber
15           Court (Third Section)       Chamber
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Originating_body = c("Court (First Section)", 
"Court (First Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Fifth Section)", 
"Court (Second Section)", "Court (First Section Committee)", 
"Court (First Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", 
"Court (First Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Grand Chamber)", 
"Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)", "Court (Third Section)"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(dict)
structure(list(Originating_body = c("Court (Second Section)", 
"Court (Second Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Fourth Section)", 
"Court (Third Section)", "Court (First Section Committee)", "Court (Third Section Committee)", 
"Court (Fifth Section Committee)", "Court (Chamber)", "Court (Plenary)", 
"Court (Grand Chamber)", "Court (Fifth Section)", "Court (First Section)", 
"Court (Fourth Section)", "Court (Second Section)", "Court (Third Section)"
), origin.simple = c("Chamber", "Chamber", "Chamber", "Chamber", 
"Chamber", "Committee", "Committee", "Committee", "Chamber", 
"Grand Chamber", "Grand Chamber", "Chamber", "Chamber", "Chamber", 
"Chamber", "Chamber")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```